# Ionic 2: Remove background from custom component button in navbar

Tags: typescript, angular, styling, custom-component, ionic2

**Q) How do I fix the styling on the custom component below so it looks like the plus sign, with inherited styling from the `<ion-buttons>` directive?**

I'm using a custom component in my navbar: `<notifications-bell></notifications-bell>`, like so:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar header-colour>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>  
  <ion-buttons end>
    <notifications-bell></notifications-bell>
    <button>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>  
  <ion-title>Clients</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

But it's rendering with a background colour:

[image]

**Here's my component:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'notifications-bell',
    directives: [],
    template: `<button><ion-icon name="notifications-outline"></ion-icon></button>`
})
export class NotificationsBellComponent {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe edit/overwrite the CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd assume it's as simple as removing background and shadow?

```
button{
  background: none !important;
  background-color: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: yeah i know I can do that, but I wanted to see if there was a way that the framework would do this by itself without me bodging it.

Comment: Additional info on how to do that: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

Comment: It comes with its own `css` so I think you'll need to overwrite it or remove it